# Passing & (ampersands) in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

I'm sending JavaScript values via POST method using AJAX. Everything works fine except that I'm unable to send strings with `&` (ampersands). I tried `encodeURIcomponent` but nothing seems to work. Everything after the ampersand gets lost.

This is my code:

**AJAX call**

```
function chpr(gffo){

  var fd=gffo;

  var vl=document.getElementById(message).value;
  vl = encodeURIComponent(vl);

  if((vl)!=""){

    var xmlhttp;    

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","example.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("q="+fd+"&w="+vl);

  }

}
```

On the PHP side I'm fetching it as:

```
$w = $_POST['w'];
```

So for example if I want to send `Me & You`,

on the PHP side it fetches just `Me`.

Comment: Please post some PHP code so we can see what you are trying there and what you mean by 'gets lost'.

Comment: Have you used `encodeURIComponent` on your `fd` variable as well? You should post the complete javascript that leads to the ajax request, not just loose parts.

Comment: @Sidd have edited my question please have a look at it

Comment: @jeroen No I have Just encoded vl

Comment: That should do it (based on your edit...), can you post the complete js?

Comment: Also, try console.logging vl before using it in the AJAX request. Is it being properly encoded?

Comment: `xmlhttp.send("q="+encodeURIComponent(fd)+"&w="+encodeURIComponent(vl));`
works for me...

Comment: IMHO you should `fd=encodeURIComponent(gffo)`  too

Comment: Yes, encode all values. What does `var_dump($_POST);` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Encode ampersands as `%26` (URI percent encoding, cf. [rfc 3986, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all values which is sending by ajax please use below code it will be help you.

```
<?php
$q = $_POST['q'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
?>
```

You can also use $_REQUEST place of $_POST

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to send content with `XmlHttpRequest`:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

From: [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

This post: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm explains how to get the values from PHP:

```
<?php
  if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] )
  {
     echo "Welcome ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
     echo "You are ". $_POST['age']. " years old.";
     exit();
  }
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">

  Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
  Age: <input type="text" name="age" />

  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. The OP is successfully sending and receiving information so general information about how to send and receive (unencoded...) values is not really helpful.